# HLM-related inquiry - comparing the magnitude of coefficients

Tags: model, model-comparison, multilevel-analysis, dyadic-data

I've conducted two separate HLM analyses, each with two IVs predicting to the same DV in the same sample. The problem that I've encountered is that I would like to compare the **magnitude** of the resulting coefficients across each analysis to determine if they are equivalent. I'm using dyadic data, which is why I used HLM. Here is a more concrete example:

Analysis 1: DV-1

IV-1

IV-2

Analysis 2: DV-1

IV-3

IV-4

To be concrete, I want to show that a computer-based coding of a test (e.g., which produces IV-1 and IV-2) produces similar coefficients as a human-based coding of the identical test (e.g., which produces IV-3 and IV-4). That is, I would like to be able to compare the coefficients obtained for IV-1 with IV-3 (which are the same variable, but one was produced using a computer and the other by a human), and IV-2 with IV-4 (again, these two should be the same variable, one produced by a computer and the other by a human), to examine whether they are equivalent in magnitude. Is this possible? Is there a statistical test that exists to quantify the difference?

To clarify, I'm not interested in mediation per se. Rather, I'm just interested in whether the resulting coefficients are equivalent in magnitude (regardless of whether they are accounting for different variation in the DV).

Comment: I've often found a Bayesian approach using JAGS, Stan, etc. to be very helpful in performing these kinds of more unusual hypothesis tests, particularly in the context of hierarchical models. For example, if you could integrate it into one model, you could get a posterior density on the difference between the two coefficients.